# Variable expansion in expect script

Tags: variables, expect, expansion

Hope someone can help with this variable expansion inside expect script.
I assign values to variables in a loop like Ex:

```
for {set i 1} {$i<=10} {incr i 1} {
 set IO$i [expr {$i + 1}]
}
```

I can get the variable values one by one by ex:

```
send_user "IO1 value is: $IO1"
send_user "IO2 value is: $IO2"
...
```

Is there a way that I can get the variable values inside the for loop, something like:

```
send_user "IO$i value is: $XXXXXX ?
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried couple diff. combinations of:  send_user "IO$i value is: ${IO$i}" , send_user "IO$i value is: ${IO${i}}"

Comment: You need to learn the [tag:tcl] language before using Expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set` command to *get* values as well as set them

```
send_user "IO$i value is: [set IO$i]"
# ........................^^^^^^^^^^
```

But it will be more convenient to use an array instead of a dynamically created variable

```
for {set i 1} {$i<=10} {incr i 1} {
 set IO($i) [expr {$i + 1}]
}
send_user "IO($i) value is: $IO($i)"
```

Comment: Wonderful.  I tried both methods you mentioned and both work.  A BIG Thank you Mr. Jackman...